# Assign same value/id to duplicate entries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My table

```
|   i   |   j  |

| kathy |  25 |

| Kathy |  45  |     

| Jason|  34   |

| James|  67  |

| Kathy|  37  |

| Emily|  56  |

| Jason|  89   |
```

I want same value/id(refer col 'k') to be generated against emp names(col'i') irrespective of column having repeated entries.

As the entries in the col 'i' will be dynamic ,cannot use case statement here.
Is there a way to do this in `MySQL` dynamically?

**Expected o/p:**

```
|   i   |   j  | k |

| kathy |  25 |  1 |

| Kathy |  45  |  1 |   

| Jason|  34   |  2 |

| James|  67  |   3 |

| Kathy|  37  |   1 |

| Emily|  56  |   4 |

| Jason|  34   |  2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses variables and a subquery:

```
select t.*, n.rn
from t join
     (select n.name, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from (select distinct name from t) n cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) n
     on t.name = n.name;
```

Note that the order of the result set might (and probably will) differ from your original table.  To get results in a particular order, you need an `order by` and there is no obvious column for such ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using below:

```
set @pk1 ='';
set @rn1 =0;

SELECT  i,
        j,
        rank
FROM
(
  SELECT  i,
          j,
          @rn1 :=  if(@pk1=i, @rn1, @rn1+1) as rank,
          @pk1 := i  
  FROM
  (
    SELECT  i,
            j
    FROM    tbl1
    ORDER BY i
) A
) B;
```

Comment: Thanks Mittal, But I'm not allowed to use set operator for my queries